# Get distance between point A and C when their distances with a common point B is known

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, machine-learning, euclidean-algorithm

**Background**:

My plan is to get the overall euclidean distance matrix for all the vectors in N number of dataset. Each dataset is basically an array of n-dimensional points. For e.g: A dataset can be like [[1,2,3,...n],[1,2,3,..n],...[1,2,3,n]]. However, the datasets are not gonna be shared to a single entity for which I cannot compile them and thus will not know all the points to calculate pairwise euclidean distance for some similarity calculation and clustering analysis and modeling. However, I will be only notified what are the common vectors in the datasets and distance of the vectors in any dataset with respect to those common vectors without knowing or passing the point's coordinates.
If the dataset could be shared in the same model, I wouldn't have to face this distributed calculation problem.

**Problem**:

Given,

1. The euclidean distance between vector A and vector B
2. The euclidean distance between vector B and vector C

How to calculate the euclidean-distance between point A and C?

Thanks in advance.

**Important to mention:**
So far I have been trying to use @AmanKushwaha mentioned formula to calculate the euclidean-distance between point A and C via Python script. Thankfully, it gives me the correct distance for 2-dimensional vectors. But as I stated above, instead of 2-dimensional vectors, each dataset can consist an array of N dimensional vectors where the value of N can be upto 20,000  (Please see the latest comments).

Comment: You should include what you have tried to solve this problem instead of just posting your questions and expecting an answer.

Comment: Can’t be done since there are infinitely many possible answers. Best you can do is give lower and upper bounds of the distance

Comment: $min(AC)=0, max(AC)= AB+BC$. Rest depends on $\angle ABC$

Comment: As a further reinforcement that you need $\angle ABC$, see [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), which demonstrates that the distance between points $A$ and $C$ varies with the angle.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Actually, $\min(AC) = \left| AB - BC \right|$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yeah.Right! I can't enforce  the distances $AB$ and $BC$ to be equal for the sake of minimum. All I can do is make the $\angle ABC=0$ where minimum would exist for given distances $AB$ and $BC$. As such, $\min(AC) = \left| AB - BC \right|$. Sorry for my previous comment.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, point A and C belong to different dataset where each dataset is being train in separate local ML model for which I cannot get angle ABC.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thank you. but what can be the upper bound? |AB + BC| ? I know it's tough to get a realistic value but given the fact that we can accept considerable amount of error, is it justifiable or safe to assume the distance between A and C is (min(AC) + max(AC))/2?

Comment: @ShihabUllah Then you can not find the distance between $A$ and $C$.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, is it not possible even if I consider angle ABC=0 ? Is there any way or approach you can recommend to get the distance of AC with Euclidean distance value of AB and BC?

Comment: @ShihabUllah if you assume $\angle ABC=0$ then the distance $AC$ will be exactly equal to $|AB-BC|$. Without knowing $\angle ABC$ you can get the distance $AC$ since it varies with that angle, meaning that the distance is a function of that angle. It's not about method or approach, what you are asking is the value of $f(\theta)$ without giving any value of $\theta$, so what the function $f$ is well defined, unless and until an argument is passed in the function you can't get a unique value independent of the variable(argument).

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, what about when the angle is 45, 90,180 and 360 degree? Also, is there any way or approach you can recommend to get the distance of AC with Euclidean distance value of AB and BC?

Comment: @ShihabUllah Welcome to Math SE. I didn't write anything about [Aman Kushwaha](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/819784/aman-kushwaha)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217205/get-distance-between-point-a-and-c-when-their-distances-with-a-common-point-b-is#comment8754282_4217205)'s upper bound of $AB + BC = \left| AB + BC \right|$, because it's correct. This occurs when $A$ and $C$ are opposite points of a line segment, with $B$ being a point in between. Then $\measuredangle ABC = 180^{\circ}$, so using $\cos(\angle ABC) = -1$ in the answer below also gives this result.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, I have tried to use your mentioned formula to calculate the Euclidean distance of AC with a python script. But, when I use π+tan−1mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB (when mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB<0) it gives me wrong result. It gives me correct result only when I omit or dont add π (when mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB<0). Most important problem is I am unable to find AC when A,B,C are n-dimensional vectors. In laymans term, what will be the formula when its (x,y, ...) coordinates instead of (x,y) coordinates. I will gladly accepting your answer if you can help me get it right please! I will really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @ShihabUllah I've edited my answer,$\textbf{read from Edit 2}$. I've tried to answer all the questions that can originate regarding the method I'm telling now. Also, read the notes (i) to (v) to understand why using the vectors is important and the method I shared shall not be disapproved for some reason involving "datasets" considering my previous methods were viable.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, w.r.t note(v), I do not calculate the slopes and the distances mentioned in edit 1, it'll be provided by ext. sources. If there are two sources named 1 and 2, 1 will calculate m_AB and AB and pass it to me, 2 will calculate m_BC and BC and pass it to me. Like this, there'll be atleast 8-12 sources. W.r.t note (iii), vectorBA and vectorBC will be calculated and send to me, then I will calculate vectorAC using them. But, I wont have A and C to calculate distanceAC from vectorAC. How can we modify the formula stated in Edit 1 to calculate slope of n-dimensional vector and use it?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, I am new to this kind of platform.  I am really thankful for all of your edits. If you think I am going to different direction and you are answering different sub-questions, I can create another stackexchange questions if you want  to answer there while accepting your answer here. However, to me it seems like the same question even though it took a lot of effort and time from you. I am not sure but if its possible for 2-dimensional points like you mentioned in Edit 1  without knowing A,C individually maybe its also possible for n-dimensional points!

Comment: @ShihabUllah you already got the distance $AC$. It is the magnitude of $\vec{AC}$

Comment: @ShihabUllah you don't need the individual points $A$ and $C$. You just need $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$. That's it. Read edit 2, ignore the notes. The method is there.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, Lets say the points are A = [2,3,4,5,16], B = [17,18,15,12,19] and C = [9,1,3,0,4]. Euclidean distance between A and B is 25.0798, that between B and C is 29.4278 and that between A and C is 14.9331. However when I calculate the euclidean distance between A and C using your given formula it gives 52.6022 instead of 14.9331.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, This is the simple python code I wrote to evaluate the calculation: import numpy as np
vector_BA = np.subtract(B,A)
vector_BC = np.subtract(C,B)
vector_AC = np.subtract(vector_BC,vector_BA)
print("vector_BC = " ,vector_BC)
print("vector_BA = ", vector_BA)
print("vector_AC = ", vector_AC)
magnitude_AC = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(vector_AC)))
print("Distance between A and C",magnitude_AC)

Comment: @ShihabUllah I'm very sorry. Actually $\vec{BA}=\vec A -\vec B$. Rest is fine. Is it giving correct results now?.There's no chance it could be wrong.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Sure, no worries. I would really appreciate if you edit your answer by checking and validating it so that I can use it for calculating distance correctly. Sincere gratitude :)

Comment: It is done. I've edited. In your code, the only thing that needs to be changed is the first line: vector_BA = np.subtract(B,A) to this: vector_BA = np.subtract(A,B). Besides, Is the option to upvote my answer not there, since the question is closed?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, unfortunately, being a new member I dont have enough reputation to case an upvote. Your interpretation is mostly correct except in some cases. For example: For A = [2,3,4,5,16,465456,321]
B = [17,18,15,12,19,1,0]
C = [9,1,3,0,4,87654,12] ,when I calculate the euclidean distance between A and C using your given formula it gives 31631.09 instead of 377802.12. Is this an unrealistic or extreme cases? How can I minimize such errors as the error margin is high?

Comment: @ShihabUllah A difference in the distance you calculated using coordinates and the method I gave? That's not possible. There must be something wrong with the code. The proof for my method or you say verification is there in note (ii). Also the difference in the two methods is only that you are calculating $5-3$ and I am calculating the same difference as $(5-b)-(3-b)$ which is equal to $5-\not b-3+\not b=5-3$. So where's the error?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha, I have edited only the first line of the following code as per instruction and tried: "import numpy as np
A = [2,3,4,5,16,465456,321]
B = [17,18,15,12,19,1,0]
C = [9,1,3,0,4,87654,12]
vector_BA = np.subtract(A,B)
vector_BC = np.subtract(C,B)
vector_AC = np.subtract(vector_BC,vector_BA)
print("vector_BC = " ,vector_BC)
print("vector_BA = ", vector_BA)
print("vector_AC = ", vector_AC)
magnitude_AC = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(vector_AC)))
print("Distance between A and C",magnitude_AC)
print("for checking purpose:",math.dist(A,C))"
How can the result be different?

Comment: A = [2,3,4,5,16,465456,321]
B = [17,18,15,12,19,1,0]
C = [9,1,3,0,4,87654,12]
import numpy as np
vector_BA = np.subtract(A,B)
vector_BC = np.subtract(C,B)
vector_AC = np.subtract(vector_BC,vector_BA)
print("vector_BC = " ,vector_BC)
print("vector_BA = ", vector_BA)
print("vector_AC = ", vector_AC)
magnitude_AC = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(vector_AC)))
print("Distance between A and C",magnitude_AC)
#calculating directly with coordinates, see, Sir Shihab Ullah
AC1=np.subtract(C,A)
distanceAC1=np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square((AC1))))
print(distanceAC1)

Comment: Wait I am checking math.dist (AC). I don't about this. I tried the code in python and I got vector_BC =  [   -8   -17   -12   -12   -15 87653    12]
vector_BA =  [   -15    -15    -11     -7     -3 465455    321]
vector_AC =  [      7      -2      -1      -5     -12 -377802    -309]
Distance between A and C 377802.12665891653
377802.12665891653
>

Comment: @ShihabUllah I checked math.dist(A,C) ,it gives $377802.12665891653$ which is same

Comment: Here you go,  https://www.online-python.com/XfIYBSZNOj  copy my code, use any python interpreter you'll get the same results.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha,  I think something weird going on in my jupyter notebook or python. If you see the screenshot in the link below, you will see that its giving me different results! So weird and frustrating I must say.
https://ibb.co/yBHyxhv

Comment: @ShihabUllah You got the vector $\vec{AC}$ right. The problem is in magnitude_AC. Have you tried the code in online interpreters?

Comment: Yes, the online interpreters give accurate result. It is my jupyter notebook and pythons issue. I will try to fix it on my own. Thank you @AmanKushwaha for constant and swift support for days. YOU ARE THE BEST. If I have any other related queries, I will tag you here with new question link so that you can look into it. I hope thats fine. :) Take care :)

Comment: @ShihabUllah Thank you too. Yeah, that's fine. I don't know why moderators are still allowing us to chat like this, here. I want to ask you about something which, if asked here, might cause trouble to my account. So, is there any other way? It's just one question. That's all. I'll not take much of your time.

Comment: Please ask me the question. Also I almost forgot @AmanKushwaha, if the vector was 2 dimensional, then one might need to remove pi if (mBC−mAB)/(1+mBCmAB)<0 otherwise it gives incorrect theta value. Do you know the reasoning behind it? Maybe one last edit of your answer? Here is the python code for it: https://www.online-python.com/6OyTpBhVgM

Comment: @ShihabUllah I've mailed you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\angle ABC$ is known, say $\angle ABC=\theta$ then you can get the exact distance between the points $A$ and $C$ for given distances $AB$ and $AC$ using the following rule:

$AC=\sqrt{AB^2+BC^2-2AB.BC \cos{\theta}} \tag{i} \label{i}$ which is nothing but cosine rule.

Yes, you can find $AC$ for different angles between $AB$ and $BC$ by putting $\theta=0°,45°,90°,360°$ etc. in the above rule.

$\mathbf{Edit1:}$

After reading your comments, I understand that you can not use the coordinates of $A$ and $C$ to calculate the distance $AC$ but you can use a different attribute from both the datasets together even if that attribute involves the use of coordinates of $A$ and $C$ in respective datasets, like you said you can use $\angle ABD$ and $\angle CBD$ if $D$ is another common point to calculate $\angle ABC$

Well then, If that's the case then there's no need to look for any other common points. You can simply calculate slope of line $AB$ and $BC$ in the dataset containing $A$ and $C$ respectively and then use the slopes to calculate the angle between them. Here's how

Let $A\equiv (a_1,a_2) , B \equiv (b_1,b_2) ,C \equiv (c_1,c_2)$

$m_{AB}=\frac{b_2-a_2}{b_1-a_1}$

$m_{BC}=\frac{b_2-c_2}{b_1-c_1}$

Now, using both datasets together $\tan{\angle ABC}=\tan{\theta}=\frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}}\text{   ( }0°\leq \theta \leq 180°) $

$$\implies\theta=\begin{cases} \tan^{-1}{\frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}}}\text{   (if } \frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}} \gt 0)\\
\pi + tan^{-1}{\frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}}}\text{   (if } \frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}} \lt 0)\\
90° \text{  (if } \frac{m_{BC}-m_{AB}}{1+m_{BC} m_{AB}} \text{ is not defined or } m_{BC} m_{AB}=-1)\end{cases}$$

The case for $m_{AB}=m_{BC}$ is left since here $\theta$ can be either $0°$ or $180°$ but actual value can't be known using $\tan{\theta}$ which is zero for both the angles and clearly $\cos{\theta}$ differs significantly at $0°$ and $180°$ making the difference in distance $AC$. This is simply the case when lines $AB$ and $BC$ are parallel and hence, coincident since the lines share a common point $B$ and the problem we are facing is that we can't know if $B$ lies between $A$ and $C$ (i.e., $\theta =180°$) or $B$ is one of the extremes (i.e., $\theta =0°$).

Evaluate $\cos{\theta}$ using the $\theta$ found above and use
it in $(\ref{i})$ to get the required distance $AC$

$\mathbf{Edit2:}$

Now that you mentioned that these are vectors we are dealing with, it becomes quite simple now if we can use $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ from one dataset to calculate $\vec{BA}$. Similarly we use, $\vec B$ and $\vec C$ from another dataset to calculate $\vec{BC}$

Then, $$\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}-\vec{BA}$$

The distance $AC$ is thus equal to $|\vec {AC}|$

$\mathbf{Note:}$

(i) The difference from previous methods is that now, not only we have distances $AB$ and $BC$ (which are magnitudes of their respective vectors) but we also have their direction, so the problem of finding the angle between $AB$ and $AC$, specifically $\angle ABC$ is now resolved.

(ii) What we've actually done there
appears like cheating because we actually
used the coordinates of $A$ and $C$
together (indirectly) from different datasets to get
the vector $\vec{AC}$ and hence the distance
$AC$. Here's how we did it:

Let $\vec{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
           a_{1} \\
           a_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           a_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} , \vec{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
           b_{1} \\
           b_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           b_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} , \vec{C}=\begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1} \\
           c_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           c_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}$ be three $n-$ dimensional column vectors such that $\vec A, \vec B$ are in one dataset and $\vec B, \vec C$ are in another.

Now, calculating $\vec{BA}$ from the first dataset, we get $$\vec{BA}= \vec A - \vec B = \begin{bmatrix}
           a_{1}-b_1 \\
           a_{2}-b_2 \\
           \vdots \\
           a_{n}-b_n
         \end{bmatrix} $$.

Similarly, calculating $\vec{BC}$ from the second dataset, we get $$\vec{BC}= \vec C - \vec B = \begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1}-b_1 \\
           c_{2}-b_2 \\
           \vdots \\
           c_{n}-b_n
         \end{bmatrix} $$.

Hence, $$\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}-\vec{BA}=  \begin{bmatrix}
           a_{1}-c_1 \\
           a_{2}-c_2 \\
           \vdots \\
           a_{n}-c_n
         \end{bmatrix}$$

$\therefore AC=|\vec{AC}|=\sqrt{(a_{1}-c_1)^2+(a_{2}-c_2)^2+ \ldots (a_{n}-c_n)^2}$

Look, the coordinates have been used.

(iii) Now the question is, can we use these vectors like $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ from the respective datasets which look like using the coordinates directly just calling it by other name. It is true that these vectors hold information about not only the lengths $AB$ and $BC$ but also the direction of these "directed" line segments, $\textbf{which is essentially what we need}$, but you can't get the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ from the $\vec{BA}$ (which is free to move anywhere in space). So, "the coordinates of $A$ and $B$" and "the vector $\vec {BA}$" are not exactly the same in terms of representing a data. The former gives the actual location of points in space and gives every kind of information possible about these points whereas the latter only gives the distance and direction of one point w.r.t other which is only a portion of information of the former.

(iv) You can also notice that, using the method above, we are only getting the vector $\vec{AC}$ and so the distance $AC$ and not the coordinates of $A$ and $C$, neither have we used these coordinates directly from the datasets to calculate $AC$. So, is there any other way to calculate the distance $AC$ using only the distances $AB$ and $BC$ not the vectors? $\textbf{No!}$ Believe it or not, you have to use the coordinates in some way or other to get the distance $AC$. As I have already said, the distance $AC$ varies with the position of these points in datasets (more specifically, the direction of one point w.r.t. other) and as such the values of distances $AB$ and $BC$ are not enough to get the distance $AC$.

(v) Assuming that you are not getting the distances like $AB$ and $AC$ from some external source and you are actually calculating these distances yourself using the coordinates you get from respective datasets, then why not use the coordinates to calculate the vectors instead holding the information (including the value of distance, the magnitude) we need to calculate $AC$. Moreover, since you had no problem in $\textbf{using the coordinates}$ to calculate the slopes for different pairs of points in a dataset and then using these slopes together to get the $\angle ABC$ in the previous method, I believe you shouldn't have any problem with using the vectors from different datasets together only because the use of coordinates looks more explicit here.

$\textbf{Edit 3:}$

From one source, get the vector $\vec{BA}$ calculated. From another source, get the vector $\vec{BC}$ calculated.

Once, you get these two vectors, calculate $\vec{AC}$ using the following formula $$\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}-\vec{BA}$$
Then you just have to calculate the magnitude of this vector. I hope you have some inbuilt functions to calculate the magnitude of a given vector, if not, you can make one. Here:

The vector $\vec{AC}$ will be like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
           d_1 \\
           d_2\\
           \vdots \\
           d_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}$$

Square the elements of these vectors, then add them and take positive square root. That's it. The distance $AC$ is nothing but the magnitude of $\vec{AC}$ which is $\sqrt{(d_1)^2+(d_2)^2+ \ldots (d_n)^2}$

$\textbf{I repeat, you are not using the coordinates of $A$ and $C$}$
Two different sources are using them to get the vectors, and you use the vectors to get the distance.

$$\textbf{The End}$$

Comment: so the question now comes, how can I know the angle ABC when A and C belongs to different dataset and Bis the common point in both dataset? Thank you for your effort and explanation even though without finding that angle I cannot get the distance AC

Comment: @ShihabUllah So you mean you have the coordinates of both $A$ and $C$ but they are in different datasets so they can't be used together to compute the distance? But you have $B$ in both so you can calculate $AB$ and $BC$ and then you can use them to calculate $AC$? Or do you just have the distances $AB$ and $AC$?

Comment: yes exactly the first assumption. I have B in both so Ican calculate AB and BC and then I want to use them to calculate AC

Comment: @ShihabUllah so you can use AB and AC ($\textbf{which belong to different datasets}$) together to calculate AC but you can't use the coordinates of A and C together because they belong to different datasets! Sounds interesting. However this could be true since I don't have any idea what information can you get out of these datasets.

Comment: I can get the euclidean distance of A and B, that of B and C along but cannot use the (x,y) cordinates  of the three points.

Comment: @ShihabUllah If you could get at least one more point say, D in common in both the datasets then you can calculate $\angle ABD$ and $\angle CBD$ in respective datasets and then use them together for calculating $\angle ABC$ but that would still be cumbersome and many different cases are needed to be considered for getting $\angle ABC$ using the two angles in different datasets. Moreover, I'm not sure if you can use those two angles in respective datasets together to calculate  $\angle ABC$  and hence the distance $AC$.

Comment: I will have more than one common points like B,D etc in N datasets. How can I calculate angle ABC using from angle ABD and angle CBD? What are the different cases I need to consider?

Comment: @ShihabUllah if you can use those angles then you can definitely use the slopes of lines in respective datasets together to calculate $\angle ABC$ As such, you don't need other common points, $B$ is enough. I've now edited my answer. Please check and reply if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the valuable update. What's the proof of correctness, accuracy and error percentage of this updated approach as it's very important as I will be doing medical data analysis? Can you refer me to some resources to look into it? Importantly, let's say I have N number of common points available for both datasets, can I use this approach for all N number of common points in D number of dataset, calculate D number of AC and average them to get more realistic or accurate result?

Comment: I have tried to use your mentioned formula to calculate the Euclidean distance of AC with a python script. But, when I use π+tan−1mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB (when mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB<0) it gives me wrong result. It gives me correct result only when I omit or dont add π (when mBC−mAB1+mBCmAB<0). Most important problem is I am unable to find AC when A,B,C are n-dimensional vectors. In laymans term, what will be the formula when its (x,y, ...) coordinates instead of (x,y) coordinates. I am gladly accepting your answer if you can help me get it right please. I will really appreciate it. Sincerely thankful to you

Comment: @ShihabUllah In note(ii), I wrote "Look the coordinates have been used". That didn't mean I used the coordinates of points $A$ or $C$. I was just emphasizing how I used the vectors to get the distance which needed the coordinates, specifically the square of difference between the coordinates. Read edit (iv) and edit(iii)- where I wrote about the information carried by the vector BA and BC is less than that of coordinates of A and C, but that is sufficient to get the distance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way to find the first the equation in Aman's answer

Translate the plane so that $A$ coincides with the origin, and then rotate the plane such that $B$ lies on the positive end of the $OX$ axis. This preserves the distances between the points.

The points $C$, thus, are all the points $(x,y)$ that lie in a circle of radius $BC$ centered at $(AB, 0)$. We can describe $C$ using the parametric equations of a circle,

$$
    C = (x,y)
      = (AB + BC \cos(\theta), BC\sin(\theta)),
$$

where $\theta$ is the counterclockwise angle between the $OX$ axis and the $BC$ segment, as per the image

[image]

Calculating the distance between $C$ and $A$ gives us

$$
\begin{array}{}
    AC & = & \sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2}\\
       & = & \sqrt{(AB + BC \cos(\theta))^2
             + (BC\sin(\theta))^2}\\
       & = & \sqrt{(AB)^2 + (BC)^2\cos^2(\theta) 
             + 2(AB)(BC)\cos(\theta) + (BC)^2\sin^2(\theta)}\\
       & = & \sqrt{(AB)^2 + (BC)^2 + 2(AB)(BC)\cos(\theta)}\\
\end{array}
$$

Note that $\angle ABC$ and the $\theta$ I'm using here are supplementary. This means $\cos(\angle ABC) = -\cos(\theta)$, which wields

$$
    \sqrt{(AB)^2 + (BC)^2 - 2(AB)(BC)\cos(\angle ABC)},
$$

the equation in Aman's answer.